# Работа с Grid (extjs)

Tags: extjs, javascript

Вчера начал его изучать, так что пока туплю :)

Заполнить грид данными которые возвращает скрипт в джейсоне проблем не составило, теперь поставил себе задачу передать в скрипт параметры, и тут остановился, подскажите как, а лучше дайте ссылку на ману, вот пробовал:

```
Ext.define('Article', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
          {name: 'one', type: 'string'},
          {name: 'two', type: 'string'}
        ]
      });

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Article',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: "ajax.php",
            extraParams : {
                sid: 1,
                johniek : true
            },
            actionMethods: 'POST'
        },
        autoLoad: true
 });

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store ,
        columns: [
          {text: "первая", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'one', sortable: true},
          {text: "вторая", width: 115, dataIndex: 'two', sortable: true}

        ],
        height:210,
        renderTo: 'grid'
      });
```

POST отправляется проблем нет, ответ:

```
{"one":["0","1"],"two":["2","3"]}
```

хочу это засунуть в грид, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: привет задача еще актуально ?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте компонент [Store](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.data.Store).
Вид json придется изменить... 
Тут возможны варианты в зависимости от настройки Store.
В документации все есть.